# Generating map file which shows memory range of individual components in an executable

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I am linking multiple .so files while generating an executable in linux environment. Now what I want is the memory map which shows the memory range for individual .so files linked in executable, something like

```
0x12345678 - 0x12345800  -> lib1.so
0x12345800 - 0x12345A0C  -> lib2.so
0x12345A0C - 0x12346A00  -> lib3.so
```

For generating the map file I am passing the parameter to gcc linker with "-Wl,-Map=output.map", but the generated map file doesn't show information in this format.

Is it possible to generate map files for .so files like this? If yes then can someone suggest how to generate the map file which contains information like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to generate map files for .so files like this?

It is possible to generate a map like this *at runtime* from within the process, e.g. by examining `/proc/self/maps`, or following the runtime loader `_r_debug->r_map` link list.

As tofro's answer correctly states, it is *not* possible to generate such a map at static link time, because the load address of shared libraries is not known until the binary starts running.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Just to keep the things in place for any future reader, exact location of maps may vary on different linux environments. On ubuntu 16.04 they are located at /proc/pid/task/pid/maps.

Comment: @DineshMaurya You are mistaken: `/proc/self/maps` and `/proc/$pid/task/$pid/maps` are the *exact same file* (the former is an alias for the latter).

Comment: Isn't 'self' a symbolic link to the process directory of the current process? If yes, then the output of "/proc/self/maps" to monitor the memory map from one terminal while running the executable in other terminal will give the wrong results ?

Comment: @DineshMaurya Ah, yes. I clarified the answer. *Obviously* `/proc/self` refers to the process itself, so looking at it from a different process makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

.so files are linked in *dynamically* at run time - Their load address isn't known at link time, so a map file like you want it cannot be produced.

If you want a *static map* known at link time, you need to link with static libraries or just live with the fact that it's the OS that decides at run time where the .so libs are loaded.

`ldd` will show you what external references will be needed to be resolved at load time - But it obviously cannot tell you the addresses.